# Rails *Completed 406 Not Acceptable" in production ..working in Staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am stuck with an error "**Completed 406 Not Acceptable**" in the production server which I am not facing in the staging server .

Same code is working fine in staging but not working in production .Both environment has same gems installed . I am using a rails version 3.0.10.

In my production environment , the GET request is processed as a html but in staging it is processed as js .I have defined the respond_to block only for js format . I am not sure why it is behaving differently in two environments.

Also I have tried adding the defaults format as js in the routes.rb but that also is not working.

```
match 'releases/cycle_paginate', :to => 'releases#cycle_paginate', :defaults => { :format => 'js' }
```

But this is also not working .

Below is the log for production and staging .

**Production:**

```
Started GET "/releases/cycle_paginate/2?id=4" for 10.30.10.67 at Wed Aug 14 07:13:45 -0400 2013
  Processing by ReleasesController#cycle_paginate as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4", "page"=>"2"}
```

**Staging:**

```
Started GET "/releases/cycle_paginate/2?id=53" for 10.30.10.67 at Wed Aug 14 06:42:45 -0400 2013
  Processing by ReleasesController#cycle_paginate as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"53", "page"=>"2"}
```

**Controller:**

```
def cycle_paginate

  @release = Release.find(params[:id])

  @cycles = []
  @cycles = Kaminari.paginate_array(@release.cycles) \
                  .page(params[:page]) \
                  .per(5)
  last_page = @cycles.num_pages
  if params[:page].to_i > last_page
    @cycles = @cycles.page(last_page)
  else
    @cycles = @cycles.page(params[:page].presence || 1)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

This is making me mad. Appreciate your help.

Routes.rb

```
    `Tcm::Application.routes.draw do        match "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "create", :as => "login"
      match "logout", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "destroy", :as => "logout"
      resources :ic_tree_items do
        get :children, :on => :member
        get :nonmem_rel_children, :on => :member
        get :release_children, :on => :member
        get :cycle_children, :on => :member
      end
      resources :users
      resources :ic_revisions
      resources :tester_release_assignments
      resources :roles
      resources :project_platform_config_assignments
      resources :platform_configs
      resources :user_sessions

      match 'ic_runs/execute_multiple', :to => 'IcRuns#execute_multiple', :as => "execute_multiple_ics", :via => :put

      resources :ic_runs
      resources :reports
      resources :testruns

      match "cycles/add_ics", :to => "cycles#add_ics"

      resources :cycles
      resources :releases do
        get :autocomplete_user_name, :on => :collection
      end
      resources :projects
      resources :tasks
      resources :steps
      resources :asserts

      match 'releases/mass_assign', :to => 'Releases#mass_assign', :as => 'mass_assign_releases', :via => :post
      match 'ics/mass_action', :to => 'Ics#mass_action', :as => 'mass_action_ics', :via => :post
      match 'ics/filter' ,:to=>'Ics#filter',:via=> :post
      match 'taggings/selection_options', :to => 'Taggings#selection_options', :as => 'selection_option_taggings',:via => :post
      match 'tags/filter',:to=>'Tags#filter',:via=> :post
      resources :ics
      resources :tags

      root :to => "Home#index"
      match ':name' => 'Projects#show'
      match 'ic_revisions/update', :to => 'ic_revisions#update'
      match 'ic_revisions/clone_task', :action => "clone_task", :controller=>"ic_revisions"
      match 'ic_revisions/definition_textbox', :to => 'ic_revisions#definition_textbox'
      match 'tasks/destroy', :action => "destroy", :controller=>"tasks"
      match 'steps/destroy', :action => "destroy", :controller=>"steps"
      match 'asserts/destroy', :action => "destroy", :controller=>"asserts"
      match 'cycles/:id/delete', :action => "destroy", :controller=>"cycles"
      match 'ic_revisions/manage/:ic_id', :to => 'ic_revisions#index', :as => "manage_ic_revisions"
      match 'cycles/:id/add_ics', :to => 'cycles#add_ics'
      match 'cycles/del_cycle_ic', :to => 'cycles#del_cycle_ic'
      match 'cycles/add_ic_run', :action => "add_ic_run", :controller=>"cycles", :via => :post
      match 'releases/:id/add_ics', :to => 'releases#add_ics'
      match 'users/lead/:id', :to => 'users#show_lead', :as => "lead"
      match 'users/tester/:id', :to => 'users#show_tester', :as => 'tester'
      match 'users/edit/:id', :to => 'users#edit', :as => 'users_edit'
      match 'cycles/add_cq', :to => 'cycles#add_cq',:as=>'cycles_add_cq'
      match 'ic_runs/update_ics', :to => 'ic_runs#update_ics'
      match 'ic_runs/cycle/:cycle_id', :to => 'ic_runs#cycle', :as => 'cycle_ic_runs'
      match 'ic_runs/edit_result', :to => 'ic_runs#edit_result'
      match 'ic_runs/ic_run_list/:id', :to => 'ic_runs#ic_run_list', :as => 'ic_runs_list'
      match 'reports',:to=>'reports#index'
      match 'reports/update_releases', :to=>'reports#update_releases'
      match 'reports/update_cycles', :to=>'reports#update_cycles'
      match 'reports/show', :to=> 'reports#export_reports'
      match 'ics/on_update_root', :to=>'ics#on_update_root'
      match 'ic_runs/export_all', :to => 'ic_runs#export_all'
      match 'ics/on_update_suite', :to=>'ics#on_update_suite'
      match 'ic_runs/destroy', :to => 'ic_runs#destroy', :key=>:ic_run_ids
      match 'cycles/:id/clone', :action => "clone", :controller=>"cycles"
      match 'releases/:id/clone', :action => "clone", :controller=>"releases"
      match 'cycles/:id/delete_ics', :action => "delete_ics", :controller=>"cycles"
      match 'releases/update_testers', :to => 'releases#update_testers'
      match 'releases/update_testers(/:page)', :action => "update_testers", :controller=>"Releases", :page => :page
      match 'releases/cycle_paginate', :to => 'releases#cycle_paginate'
      match 'releases/cycle_paginate(/:page)', :action => "cycle_paginate", :controller=>"Releases", :page => :page
      match 'ics/new_ics', :to =>'ics#', :action => "new_ics", :controller => "Ics"
      match 'ics/obsolete_ics', :to=>'ics#', :action=>"obsolete_ics", :controller=>"Ics"
      match 'ics/new_ic_stub', :to=>'ics#', :action=>"new_ic_stub", :controller=>"Ics"
      match 'ics/index', :to=>'ics#', :action=>"index", :controller=>"Ics"
      match 'releases/rel_all_ics', :action => "rel_non_member", :controller => "Releases"
      match 'cycles/cycle_non_member', :action=>"cycle_non_member", :controller=>"Cycles"
    end
```

`

Comment: Can you post your routes config? 99% of the time 406 is because of conflict in routes.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but only with certain users and I can't replicate it so I'd be interested to hear if anyone has a solution. I see it in the logs but don't know how it's occurring.

Comment: @SweetieBelle But I have same routes.rb deployed in staging and production

Comment: Are you actually expecting JS or JSON here? Is this by any chance coming from an ajax request? The difference in probably in the accept headers somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisHeald  am expecting JS in my respond_to block .Can you further ellaborate on accept headers . So as I am expecting JS , so I had a file with name cycle_paginate.js.erb in my views which is partially rendering my cycle_paginate.html.haml.

Comment: How are you specifying that you want JS in the request? What does the Accept header of the request look like?

Comment: I am doing doing a render partial from show view for implementing ajax loading so in the render partial page I have given the below params
params => {:controller => "Releases", :action => "cycle_paginate"},:param_name => 'page', :remote => true

My cycle_paginate action in controller will do a JS format

Comment: I think it's to do with using `remote: true`, which I also use where I'm experiencing this problem. In my case it may be to do with browsers that don't have JS enabled properly. I think Rails UJS is designed to fallback to non-JS methods so this may be what is happening.

Comment: But same piece of code is working fine in staging .My only concern is it is not working in production ..

Answer (score 7):

Finally I got the solution after a lot of debugging  ..

My request accept header was expecting a HTML while server was returning a Javascript response so that was not acceptable by browser.

In my case a Javascript file was missing the javascript_include_tag in the application.html.erb .The Javascript missing was ***jquery_ujs.js*** .Basically this sets the accept header for ajax loading .The Javascripts included in this tag will be cached and stored. 
So I added the missing Javascript and removed the cached folder and YIPPEE, my problem got resolved.

I will give a small example that I learnt somewhere from a blog.  It seems that it will be helpful for others to understand the 406 error.

406 error can be understood as below:
 Suppose I've asked you for a book to read, but I can only read books in English and French. If you only have books in German, you would give me an empty response with a ***"406 - not acceptable" status.***

***406 is the server telling you "I have what you asked for, but you won't accept them".***

That's what Accept headers in the http request are for.  For instance, if the HTTP request includes directions that it will only accept "img/jpg" MIME type, the server would send a 406 status if the file requested is an Excel spreadsheet.

To diagnose:

- request one of these pages and analyze the http request headers
- Pay attention to the MIME type of the responses, the Character Set, GZIP encoding*

"406 not acceptable" is an unusual status code - the most common are 200, 404, 500, 301.  You only see a 406 when something is wrong with the server, usually something silly but hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  My issue was that I was making an HTML request, but my respond_to block was only accepting js.

so I needed to change this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

And then it all worked again.