# why jquery.submit() not working in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

currently I am upgrading a rails 3 project to rails 4. rails 3 project was developed using prototype and jquery framworks. After moving to rails4 we dropped prototype js framework.

in rails 3 some action are updated using prototype like this,

in client side,

> jQuery('#form').submit();

in controller,

```
render :update do |page|
page.replace_html  "elem_id", :partial => @something
end
```

In rails 4 we dorpped prototypejs so we modified AJAX call like this

in client side,

> jQuery('#form').submit();

in controller,

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
```

and in view, we created a `js.erb` file. But it is not working property. I am getting error like this

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)
```

but records are saving properly in backend. Then I googled and got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236649/rails-completed-406-not-acceptable-in-production-working-in-staging). But no result.

So, Instead of `jQuery('#form').submit();` if I try like this,

```
jQuery.ajax({
data: data: jQuery('#my_form').serialize(),
type: "POST",
url: jQuery('#my_form').attr("action"),
success: function(data)
{
  alert("success");
}
});
```

it is working correctly.

why `jQuery('#form').submit();` is not working for me? is there any alternate available. Because `jQuery('#form').submit();` used in many places and I don't want to replace those with  `jQuery.ajax({...})`

Comment: jQuery is javascript framework, it only handles html and dom, it doesn't care about the backend. That submit should work if your forms id="form" ie. <form id="form"...?

Comment: yes the form id and all correct..

Comment: Your form should be remote form. Add `remote: true` to your form in view